# Proving some identities making use of properties of complex numbers

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

**Problem:** Show that for real $\phi$ we have the following identities: \begin{align*} & a) \ \sin(3 \phi) = 3 \cos^2 (\phi) \sin(\phi) - \sin^3 (\phi), \\ & b) \  1 + e^{i \phi} + e^{2 i \phi} + \ldots + e^{i n \phi} = e^{\frac{i}{2} n \phi} \frac{\sin (\frac{1}{2}(n+ 1) \phi)}{\sin \big(\frac{1}{2} \phi\big)}. \end{align*}

**Attempt:** For $(a)$, I did the following. We have that $$ e^{3 i \phi} = \cos (3 \phi) + i \sin (3 \phi) $$ and so \begin{align*} (e^{i \phi})^3 &= ( \ cos \phi + i \sin \phi)^3 \\ &= \cos^3 \phi + 3i \cos^2 \phi \sin \phi - 3 i \cos \phi \sin^2 \phi - i \sin^3 \phi \\ &= \underbrace{(\cos^3 \phi - 3 \cos \phi \sin^2 \phi)}_{\cos 3 \phi} + i \underbrace{(3 \cos^2 \phi \sin \phi - \sin^3 \phi)}_{\sin 3 \phi}
\end{align*} With this argument I proved (a). But I don't know how to prove (b), help would be appreciated!

Comment: In $(b)$ the case $\phi=0$ should be excluded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First apply the formula for the sum of a geometric progression(assume $\phi\ne 0 )$:
$$1 + e^{i \phi} + e^{2 i \phi} + \ldots + e^{i n \phi}=\frac{e^{i(n+1)\phi}-1}{e^{i\phi}-1}$$
Break the numerator and denominator like this:$$\frac{e^{i(n+1)\phi}-1}{e^{i\phi}-1}=\frac{e^{i\phi(n+1)/2}}{e^{i\phi /2}}\cdot\frac{e^{i\phi(n+1)/2}-e^{-i\phi(n+1)/2}}{e^{i\phi /2}-e^{-i\phi /2}}$$
Now I think you can simplify the thing to get the form you want.

Comment: Is your formula equivalent to $ \frac{1 - e^{i n \phi}}{1-e^{i \phi}} = 1 + e^{i \phi} + \ldots + e^{i n \phi}$ ?

Comment: @Kamil the LHS in your comment is wrong, the power in the numerator should be $i(n+1)\phi$ since there are $n+1$ terms in the RHS. And yes, I have derived the expression from that, so it should be equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Geometric series: $$\sum_{k=0}^n q^k = \frac{1-q^{n+1}}{1-q}$$ for $q\neq 1$